# How to email a non-contact in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app

How can I send an email to someone who isn't already known by Mail?

Every time I type the new email address and try to enter it by:

- pressing enter
- clicking outside the field
- clicking the (+) button at the end of the To: field

it enters the email of the top-selection from the drop-down, instead of what I typed.

The only solution I have found is to type the email elsewhere, and paste it into the To: field.

How can I type the email directly into the To: field and force Mail.app to use the email I have typed?

Comment: The prediction list should vanish as soon as you've typed more characters than are in any prediction. john@ might match several possibilities, but john@xy then doesn't & the list disappears

Comment: Have you tried simply pressing space after entering the complete email of the person?